# Google Maps API Grey background

Tags: api, maps

I have problem with Google Maps on my site.
Maps and code works locally but when i publish map it shows only gray background.
I have Joomla site.
Please could someone help me.
This is my code:

```
<head>
     <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="/maps/westcampus.js"></script>

<script>
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.42362457157549, -122.0921247138165),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: 10
});

for (var x in westcampus) {
    var building = westcampus[x];
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(building.lat,building.lng);
    addMarker(map, building.name, location);
}
}
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
function addMarker(map, name, location) {

    var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
    bounds.extend (location);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') infowindow.close();
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: name
    });
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    map.fitBounds (bounds);
}

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>   


<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and DB

```
var westcampus = [{'name':'Google West Campus 1','lat':37.423901,'lng':-122.091497,'ost': "Ostatak!"},
{'name':'Google West Campus 2','lat':37.424194,'lng':-122.092699,'ost': "Ostatak!"},
{'name':'Google West Campus 3','lat':37.423901,'lng':-122.092456,'ost': "Ostatak!"}];
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with the code you're using.

So the problem is with the server, and where it's requesting the map from.

Are you running SSL, and trying to request the JavaScript via HTTP ? Maybe remote to the server and see if you can run the page locally there. Investigate the network with chrome of fiddler. Might be returning 403 somewhere or something along those lines.

Or a load timing issue. Sometimes google maps need the resize event called once the map triggers the idle event. So it recalculates the bounds of the map tiles.

Can't really suggest anything else. Good luck.

Comment: "Sometimes google maps need the resize event called once the map triggers the idle event"  This seems to be the problem I'm having.  The map loads, and shows the Google logo in the bottom corner, but instead of an actual map I only get a grey background until I resize the window.  How can I trigger this resize effect without requiring the user to literally resize the window?

Comment: Wow, I didn't ever come back to this sorry Vincent.

Comment: I know this was awhile ago. but in the interest of completing this. The answer is google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

Comment: Thank Anthony.  That is actually exactly what I ended up doing.  I guess I'd found that suggestion elsewhere, and it works perfectly.